# Why is inotifywait -m running multiple times? (infinite loop)

Tags: linux, bash, inotify

I have a git `post-receive` script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/git/worktree

mkdir -p $GIT_WORK_TREE

while read oldrev newrev refname
do

  # ensure the working copy is set up correctly
  git checkout -f master || exit 1
  git reset --hard $newrev || exit 1

  cd $GIT_WORK_TREE

  # build the apps
  ./gradlew bootRepackage

  # install the jars
  cp foo-web/build/libs/foo-web.jar /opt/foo-staging/git-deploy/
  cp foo-scheduler/build/libs/foo-scheduler.jar /opt/foo-staging/git-deploy/

done

echo 2

exit 0
```

And then I have another script that I'm trying to use (as root) to watch the `git-deploy` directory so that I can deploy the jar files in their proper place, with the right permissions:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEPLOY_FROM_DIR=/opt/foo-staging/git-deploy
STAGING_DIR=/opt/foo-staging

/usr/bin/inotifywait -m -q --event "MODIFY,CREATE" --format '%w%f' "$DEPLOY_FROM_DIR" |
while read f; do
        noext=${f%.jar}
        svcname=${noext/foo-/foo-staging-}
        echo $svcname
        install -o foo -g foo -m 600 "$f" "$STAGING_DIR/"
        echo "Installed $f to $STAGING_DIR"
done
```

But for some reason, on a single upload, the while loop's contents run over and over, producing output indefinitely. What am I doing wrong?

*Disclaimer: I am a software developer, not an admin. Bash is (probably obviously) not my forté.*

Answer (score 1):

From `man inotifywait`:

> **-m**, **--monitor**: Instead of exiting after receiving a single event, **execute indefinitely**. The default behaviour is to exit after the first event occurs.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I misunderstood that the first time I read it. I understood it to mean that it would block indefinitely, watching for events, and output (to my pipe) for every time it sees a create/modify.